# Android linear layout on top of each other

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I am working in Android Studio, trying to layout an Activity the way I want. Unfortunately for me, my layouts are sitting on top of each other, instead of one being below the other.

This is what I want:

- View groups aligned vertically, one after the other, all aligned to
  the left

  Within each view group I have various text views etc.

Right now, I have added two Linear Layouts within a Constraint Layout.

I would expect the second Linear Layout to be immediately BELOW the first Linear Layout, because the ID fo the first layout is "layout_general_settings" and I have instructed the second layout to start at the bottom of the first layout

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="layout_general_settings"
```

However, both linear layouts are at the top of the activity – i.e. they are on top of each other / they are in the same location.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_general_settings"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        >

        <TextView
        :
        />
        <TextView
        :
        />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_temperature_settings"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="layout_general_settings"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        >

        <TextView
        :
        />
        <TextView
        :
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Garrett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing "@+id/"
In your line:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="layout_general_settings
```

It's need to be;

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_general_settings
```

Comment: Well spotted :)